# Split string with N sql commands into an array?

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-split

On PHP, what would be the best way to split a large sql string having several inserts and/or updates and/or deletes into an array with each sql command?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO tbl () VALUES ();
INSERT INTO tbl_child () VALUES ();
INSERT INTO tbl_child () VALUES ();
UPDATE tbl_child SET ... WHERE ...;
```

I can assume there is a semicolon on the end of each instruction, however there may be semicolons inside the query values, for example: field = 'part1;part2;etc'

Comment: Can you assume that every command is on a new line? If so, you can match `/;$/`

Comment: I've considered that, but it's not 100% accurate. I can assume there is allways a new line on the end of each command, but the same can be found inside the query: field = 'val1;\n val2;\n etc'

Comment: Still the beste answer, but somehow is not working with my sample string: foreach (preg_split("/;$/", $sql) as $part)
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @fcaserio why will `preg_split` work?? you have newline in field also...

Comment: Actually, I think it is a starting point. Something like preg_split("/;$(INSERT|UPDATE|DELETE)/i", $sql) might work

Answer (score 0):

Add unique string before `insert` and `update` like `-splittingstring-`

```
$sqls=str_ireplace(";insert",";-splittingstring-insert",$sqls);  <--to be replaced
$sqls=str_ireplace(";update",";-splittingstring-update",$sqls);  <--to be replaced
$arr=explode("-splittingstring-",$sqls);

foreach($arr as $sql) {
if(!empty($sql)) {
//PDO or mysqli code here...
}
}
```

**Update**
replace above lines with

```
$sqls=preg_replace("/(;)[\r|\n]+(insert|update|delete)/m", "\\1-splittingstring-\\2", $sqls);
```

Comment: @dstudeba i misunderstood the question.. i have updated my answer

Comment: Actually,that also doesn't work. The words insert and update may be found inside the field definitions as welll.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted my comment.  This works only if update and insert aren't in a string in the sql statement.  The best way would be to determine if the semicolon is in a string or not.

Comment: ya i have added the semicolon part.. but condition is there should not be space between colon and new sql query, also it should not have newline character

Comment: each sql is on a different line ending with semicolon, but semicolons may be found inside quotes, as in "field = 'val1;\n val2;\n etc'"

Comment: @fcaserio i cannot explain my answer because i am very very poor in regex... i hope it solves your problem...

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I could find was the following:

```
foreach (preg_split("/;[\r|\n]{1,2}(insert|update|delete)+/i", $qry, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) as $part) {
    if (in_array(strtolower($part), array("insert","update","delete"))) {
        $prefix = $part;
    } else if (trim($part) != "") {
        $part = $prefix . $part;
        // exec...
        $prefix = "";
    }
}
```

tks everybody specially @samlev for the initial idea